# JavaFX Alert Button Bar sizing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX Alert dialog with several `ButtonTypes` that I have added.

Problem is, when I add the button that is larger (text is longer), the rest of the buttons start to stretch out from the original size.

like this:

[image]

Where it should look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to make it so that all buttons use their preferred size?

Here is the code:

```
    ButtonType saveButtonType = new ButtonType("Save", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    ButtonType closeButtonType = new ButtonType("Close", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
    ButtonType testButtonType = new ButtonType("LONG BUTTON TEXT", ButtonBar.ButtonData.LEFT);

    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(saveButtonType, closeButtonType,testButtonType);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
Button testButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(testButtonType);
ButtonBar.setButtonUniformSize(testButton, false);
```